# Draw drop shadow only on one view below

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow

I have a `UIView` with a drop shadow. I want the shadow to be drawn **only** on a single view below. The problem is, that the view below's bounds are smaller.

Current result:

[image: current result]

Desired result:

[image: desired result]

#### Note:

The user dynamically updates the screen by dragging the blue view in or out. Hence, the solution can't be static.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: could add both views (one with the shadow, one with shadow cast on it) to a view and mask that to your desired shape?

Comment: How would I define the mask? Also, see how the view w/ shadow is actually bigger than the one below, so I couldn't use the view below's bounds for the mask, right?

Comment: The dragging blue box needs to be visible outside the mask and only cast its shadow onto the grey box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Gray view: set cliptobounds = true
2. blue view should NOT be a child of gray view, and doesn't have shadow.
3. create a subview in gray view, which looks exactly like the blue view, set shadow for this subview.

Comment: This seems rather inconvenient when dynamically updating the view's UI. I didn't put that in my post, sorry, updated it.

Comment: what inconvenient? you only need to add 4 constraints from the subview to the blue view and it will stick with blue view.

Comment: Ohhh ok I get it. Will try that.

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a holder view.
2. Create two shapes: the blue box and the grey box.
3. Combine the paths you used for the two boxes to create a third shape for masking the holder view.

[image]

```
UIView * background = [UIView new];
background.frame = self.view.bounds;
background.backgroundColor = [self colourForHex:@"#F5F5F5" andAlpha:1.0f];
[self.view addSubview:background];

UIView * holder = [UIView new];
holder.frame = CGRectMake((w-300)/2, (h-300)/2, 300, 300);
[background addSubview:holder];

UIBezierPath * boxPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[boxPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[boxPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 100)];
[boxPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
[boxPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 0)];
[boxPath closePath];

UIBezierPath * castPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[castPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 100)];
[castPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 200)];
[castPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[castPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(190, 100)];
[castPath closePath];

CAShapeLayer * boxShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
boxShape.path = boxPath.CGPath;
boxShape.fillColor = [self colourForHex:@"#1A0F53" andAlpha:1.0f].CGColor;
boxShape.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
boxShape.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
boxShape.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
boxShape.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
[holder.layer addSublayer:boxShape];

CAShapeLayer * castShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
castShape.path = castPath.CGPath;
castShape.fillColor = [self colourForHex:@"#D8D8D8" andAlpha:1.0f].CGColor;
[holder.layer insertSublayer:castShape below:boxShape];

UIBezierPath * maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath appendPath:boxPath];
[maskPath appendPath:castPath];

CAShapeLayer * maskShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskShape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[holder.layer setMask:maskShape];
```

EDIT per comment: to add the animation shown in the gif, you can add a UIPanGestureRecogniser to the view and offset as the user slides (original requirement) or, in the above, I added some code like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     boxShape.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(100, 0, 0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
            });
```

Comment: So uh I'm trying to reproduce what you showed in the gif above. Could you share your project?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean the animation itself, but the whole code cause I'm struggling to get it to work.

Comment: What bits are you struggling on? Can hit me up in chat if you like.

Comment: In fact it doesn't really matter anymore since I went with the solution LuanLai gave. I don't really know what the issue is. I have never worked with paths or shapes. I basically translated your code into Swift but it doesn't show anything but a blue rectangle. But if you could just upload the project on github or something similar, I could check out your solution too and maybe change my mind ;)

Comment: Ah ok, there is no project to stick on git, I wrote the above code specifically for your issue.